# SQL postgresql insert statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, insert

I have a following question, for example I have a following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "regions" (gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
"__gid" int8,
"name" varchar(20),
"language" varchar(7),
"population" int8);
```

And I want to insert some records, say one of the values for "name" is - 'B', what sort of code would I have to write to change 'B' to 'English-Speaking'? Is that done with some sort of trigger? So would I have to write a trigger to change the values automatically on insert? Any help greatly appriciated!!!

Comment: So you want to `insert into regions (name, ...) values ('B', ...)` and have it put `'English-Speaking'` into `name` instead? Why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: I just required to write it for college... If it is 'C' for example it would be 'French-Speaking'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [UPDATE statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-update.html) which will do what you wish, in this case:

```
UPDATE regions set name = 'English-Speaking' where name = 'B';
```

To put this in a function use something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  insert_into_wgs()
RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN
UPDATE regions SET name = 'English-Speaking' WHERE name = 'B';
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'pgpsql';
```

Then you [create a trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtrigger.html) to run this function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_update
    AFTER UPDATE ON accounts
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE
    insert_into_wgs();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it automatically - without having to run UPDATE

Comment: See my edit for a revised answer, given your comment, @AndreiIvanov

Comment: There is few changes I had to make - but it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've guessed what you mean correctly from your description:

You will need a simple `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ... FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE` trigger to invoke a PL/PgSQL trigger procedure that changes the value of the `NEW` record and then does a `RETURN NEW`.

The documentation contains abundant details, and since this is homework I'm not going to provide a complete example. Start with [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) and [PL/pgSQL trigger procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).